# Ruby's mysql2 gem using incorrect database package (MariaDB instead of MySQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql-connector

Using Windows 10 x64 and Ruby 2.7.4, trying to install the mysql2 0.5.3 gem. Normal installation fails, so I link the libraries manually. This gem was compiled using MySQL's C API (C Connector) v 6.1.11, so I download it and specify it with the `--with-mysql-dir` option during `gem install`, as such:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1"
```

Trying to execute a program using this gem yields the following error however:

```
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.1.11 but the client library is 10.5.5. (RuntimeError)
```

Suspicious, since nothing in the MySQL project has version 10.5.5. Finally, I realize the following line during installation of the gem:

```
Using msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient
```

Indeed, one of MariaDB's latest versions is 10.5.5. Why is this package being used, instead of what I'm specifying, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I noticed a similar thing. Mariadb is supposed to be an open-source drop-in replacement for mySQL after Oracle purchased mySQL. I wouldn't worry about it. Do you have a particular concern or problem that it's causing?

Comment: @LesNightingill Unfortunately yes, when I try to execute an application that depends on the mysql2 gem, it fails to do so because the gem raises the exception shown in the second code sample in my question. This is because the gem compares the versions of both libraries (the one that it was compiled with, and the dynamic one it finds in whatever directory) and forces them to be equal, to minimize issues that could arise if they're different (this is explained when the gem is installed). Maybe this MariaDB line is not the culprit of the issue, but then, what could it be?

Comment: what version of mysql is installed? (on a Mac I type mysql --version in the terminal to find out).

Comment: Server (and Client, I assume) are v. 8.0.26, and the C Connector is 6.1.11. Both x64.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MSYS 2 automatically installs lib files if you don't explicitly specify them. They should actually already be included with the connector so this might solve your problem:

```sh
$ gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby --
  '--with-mysql-lib="C:\C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib"
   --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"
   --with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1"'
```